# Commutator of vector fields from definition of Lie derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields, lie-derivative

I have the following definition of the Lie derivative $L_X$, for a vector field $X$ on a manifold $M$:
\begin{align}
L_X:\mathcal{C}^\infty (M) \rightarrow \mathcal{C}^\infty (M)
\end{align}
is a map defined by
\begin{align}
(L_Xf)(p)=(D_pf)(X(p)).
\end{align}

I then have a definition of the commutator of vector fields $[X,Y]$ defined as the vector field satisfying ($f:M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function)
\begin{align}
L_{[X,Y]}=L_X\circ L_Y - L_Y \circ L_X.
\end{align}

What I want to be able to do is find
\begin{align}
[X,Y](f)=X(Y(f))-Y(X(f))
\end{align}
from this, but I'm not quite sure how (if it's possible). My attempt starts by looking at:
\begin{align}
(L_X (L_Yf))(p)&=(L_X((D_pf)(Y)))(p)\\
&=(D_p((D_pf)(Y)))(X)(p),
\end{align}
but I get stuck here. If $\gamma_X$ is an integral curve of $X$ at the point $p\in M$, then I am using the definition
\begin{align}
(D_pf)(X(p))=\left.\frac{d}{d t}\right|_{t=0}(f\circ \gamma_X)(t),
\end{align}
but if this is the correct way to proceed, then I'm struggling to see how to use this a second time.

If there is an answer, I'd appreciate as much detail as possible about all the definitions and steps used.

Comment: What is $D_p(f)$? The Lie derivative on functions is defined as the standard directional derivative, so what you want to prove should be immediate by definition.

Comment: $D_p(f)$ is the differential of a diffeomorphism $f:M\rightarrow N$, where in this case we take $N=\mathbb{R}$, and consider $f$ as a function. I expect what I want to prove follows from definition, but I can't see the steps to do that myself, so if you could show me how that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your comment: in general $f$ is not a diffeomorphism, as $M$ may have dimension higher than one.

To answer your question: at a point $p \in M$, $D_p(f)$ is equivalent to the gradient of $f$, so $D_p(f)(X_p)$ is the directional derivative $X_pf$ of $f$. Hence
$$(L_{[X,Y]}f)_p = [X,Y]_pf,$$
and
\begin{align*}
((L_X\circ L_Y)f)_p-((L_Y\circ L_X)f)_p & = (L_XY(f))_p-(L_YX(f))_p \\
& = X_p(Y(f))-Y_p(X(f)).
\end{align*}